# Apply in a date range filter during product and customer API call in BigCommerce

Tags: bigcommerce

I am very new to BigCommerce and recently I have started developing an application in C# for which I need to call BigCommerce Rest API.But I got stuck in one area . I want to call the Customer and Product APIs based on a date range filter , for example product and customer which are created between june 20,2014 to July 21,2014 but I have not found the API documentation for this requirement. Please suggest how I can do this work.

Thanks and Regards
Utpal Maity

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to use the min_date_created and max_date_created parameters in your request. The customers resource documentation can be found here:
https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/customers#create-customer

The products documentation should also be easy to find from there as well (products resource).

Comment: thanks for your reply . But I have not found any documentation on what is the format for applying daterange filter.Based on the documentation I have tried /v2/customers.xml?min_date_created=Thu%2C+28+Nov+2013+00%3A00%3A51+GMT but it is not working.

Comment: You can also use ISO8601 format which is much easier to work with IMO. You're URL is also wrong. For the customers resource it would be something like <BC API URL>/stores/<your store_hash>/v2/customers?min_date_created=<ISO 8601 DATE>. You specify XML or JSON in the accepts portion of your webrequest object.

Comment: See here for date format info:https://developer.bigcommerce.com/blog/changelog/api-orders-date-filters

Answer (score 0):

I guess your min_date_created is not properly URL encoded. `+` is not URL encode.

You have to first get date into `RFC 2822` format then urlencode RFC 2822 date before passing it to min_date_created

EG: `Wed%2C%2015%20May%202013%2005%3A30%3A00%20%2B0000`

Answer (score 0):

From what I see Big Commerce API accepts *different* date formats in different calls. Products take dates in RFC 2822 (e.g. `Wed, 27 Aug 2014 12:34:56 GMT`) while orders accept ISO format (`2014-08-27T12:34:56Z`).

Answer (score 0):

/orders?min_date_created=Mon%2C%2018%20Sep%202017%2012%3A12%3A49%20%2B0000&max_date_created=Wed%2C%2020%20Sep%202017%2012%3A18%3A09%20%2B0000

Encoded URL {
Mon%2C%2018%20Sep%202017%2012%3A12%3A49%20%2B0000
Wed%2C%2020%20Sep%202017%2012%3A18%3A09%20%2B0000
}